# CW caused by too many editors includes the OP?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, editing, community-wiki

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17945/invitation-to-nonkosher-restaurant) was converted to community wiki by its [most recent edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/17945/revisions), which exceeded the threshold for number of editors.  The message in the revision log is "[made Community Wiki by being edited by more than 5 different editors]".

What surprised me is that the triggering edit was made by the original poster.  Is that correct behavior -- CW is triggered specifically by the number of *editors*, not *writers*, of a post, so the OP doesn't count unless he edits after posting?  It does say "editors" in the CW-ification note in the revision history; I'm asking because I had previously thought it was the number of total people involved in the post, and I'm not sure where I got that impression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Far as I know, this is currently by design. Only actual *edits* (except ones done by the Community "user") contribute to the number of people involved in the post and the original posting doesn't count.